# Where can I find static/dynamic code analysis tools for XSLT?

Tags: xslt, static, code-analysis

Are there any static or dynamic code analysis tools that analyze XSLT/XSL code?

The resources I have been able to find so far are:
1. Oxygen xml editor
2. http://gandhimukul.tripod.com/xslt/xslquality.html which looks faily basic in its capabilities

Comment: XML parsers and DTD validators already check syntax and some semantics of XML documents.  What kind of analysis results do you want?

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few testing tools and verifiers at Tony Graham's [XSLT Testing Tools](http://www.menteithconsulting.com/wiki/TestingXSLT) page. If you haven't looked there, it's a fairly comprehensive list.

Using [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/) in schema-aware mode will catch many common errors.

You've already discovered [Mukul Gandhi's XSL Quality](http://gandhimukul.tripod.com/xslt/xslquality.html) tools, which support user-added extensions. On the [xsl-list run by Mulberry Technologies](http://www.mulberrytech.com/xsl/xsl-list/) a while back, several other people contributed ideas for new rules also. You might also get help asking there.

[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/), [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_debugger.html#profiling) and [xmlspy](http://www.altova.com/) have profilers for run-time performance.

Answer (score 0):

XML Spy includes an [XSLT profiler](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xslt-profiler.html). That should fulfil your dynamic analysis needs if you can afford it.

There is also [StylusStudio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xslt_profiler.html), a [plugin for VisualStudio](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2008/02/07/announcing-the-xslt-profiler-addin-for-vs-2008.aspx) and [CatchXSL](http://download.cnet.com/CatchXSL-The-XSLT-Profiler/3000-7241_4-10074098.html) (which is free).