# Compile-time XQuery validation

Tags: functional-programming, xquery, static-analysis

Which tools exist for static analysis of XQuery functions?

Example tasks: given two XSD schemas *A* and *B* and some XQuery *f*, check that for any document *d* of type *A* its transformation *f(d)* is valid against *B*.

Or for given query generate its inverse, when exists.

This topic is unfortunately hard for googling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think [`OxygenXML`](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) is fantastic for XQuery analysis, it has its own manual [static-analysis](http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic6720.html) tools built in.

> You can use the manual validation instead: Document > Validate > Validate after configuring a transformation or a validation scenario that specified the xDB connection as the engine.

Other resources I found which where interesting on this topic [Using  XML Editor to Create or Validate an OLAC Static Repository](http://olac.googlecode.com/svn/web/NOTE/oxygen.html) and [Where can I find static/dynamic code analysis tools for XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469475/where-can-i-find-static-dynamic-code-analysis-tools-for-xslt) (Oxygen can be used with `X-Query`, `X-Path`, `XLink` to name a few).

Comment: Thank you. http://www.brics.dk/XSLV/ (via http://www.menteithconsulting.com/wiki/TestingXSLT from your second link) seems to solve my first problem. Not sure about Oxygen, but in any case I strongly prefer free command-line tools, which may be included to project. The second problem seems to be not solved now.

Comment: as far as I know oxygen is based off `Saxon-EE`.